# How echo input characters again after turning off echoing?

Tags: c++, termios

I have this code which is meant to hide my password at login screen of terminal. After login, the input all is still blank. How do I set it to normal like back to default after `getline` is done?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    termios oldt;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    termios newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

    string s;
    getline(cin, s);


    return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: Please write the solution you found as an answer and accept that (as soon as you're allowed to).

Comment: ... or in a form that you're allowed to so we don't see this in the unanswered questions query. thx.

Comment: @MvG and Barnabas: I have added the answer from the question body, with some added detail (link and explanation), as a standalone answer since he seems to have ignored your request. I have also submitted an edit to remove his answer from the question body.

Answer (score 2):

You've already saved off the previous terminal state with a get call; now you just have to restore it with a [set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/tcsetattr.html) call in the same manner as you set the new state:

```
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
```

(For future visitors: the second parameter is a flag that means the change will occur immediately.)